# Proving V is a real vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let $V$ be the set of a single element $\theta$. Let $\theta$ $\oplus$ $\theta$ $=$ $\theta$ and for any real number, $r$$\odot$ $\theta$ $=$ $\theta$. Prove that $V$ is a real vector space.

Can someone please check my solution? Thank you.

My solution:

Let $\alpha=\theta$, $\beta=\theta$, and $\gamma=\theta$

(i) $\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\beta$ $=$ $\beta$ $\oplus$ $\alpha$?

$\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\beta$ $=$ $\theta$ $\oplus$ $\theta$

$=$ $\beta$ $\oplus$ $\alpha$

The 1st property holds

(ii) $\alpha$ $\oplus$ ($\beta$ $\oplus$ $\gamma$) $=$ ($\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\beta$) $\oplus$ $\gamma$?

$=$ $\theta$ $\oplus$ ($\theta$ $\oplus$ $\theta$ )

$=$ ($\theta$ $\oplus$ $\theta$ ) $\oplus$ $\theta$ $=$ ($\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\beta$ ) $\oplus$ $\gamma$

The 2nd property holds

(iii) $\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\theta$ $=$ $\theta$ $\oplus$ $\alpha$ $=$ $\alpha$?

$=$ $\theta$ $\oplus$ $\theta$

$=$ $\theta$ $=$ $\alpha$

The 3rd property holds

(iv) $\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\beta$ $=$ $\beta$ $\oplus$ $\alpha$ $=$ $\alpha$?

Assume that $\beta=\theta$. If $\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\beta$ $=\theta$, then $\theta$ $\oplus$ $\theta$ $=$ $\theta$, this means that

$\alpha+\beta=0$ $\rightarrow$ $\beta=-\alpha$

The 4th property holds

(v) $r$$\odot$($\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\beta$ ) $=$ $r$$\odot$$\alpha$ $\oplus$ $r$$\odot$$\beta$?

$r$$\odot$($\alpha$ $\oplus$ $\beta$ ) $=$ $r$$\odot$($\theta$ $\oplus$ $\theta$ ) $=$ $r$$\odot$$\theta$ $\oplus$ $r$$\odot$$\theta$

$r$$\odot$$\alpha$ $\oplus$ $r$$\odot$$\beta$ $=$ $r$$\odot$$\theta$ $\oplus$ $r$$\odot$$\theta$

The 5th property holds

(vi) $(r + s)\odot \alpha=r\odot$$\alpha$ $\oplus$ $s\odot$$\alpha$

$=r\odot$$\theta$ $\oplus$ $s\odot$$\theta$

$=(r+s)\odot\theta=$$(r+s)\odot$$\alpha$

The 6th property holds

(vii) $1\odot \alpha = \alpha$?

$=\theta=\alpha$

The 7th property holds

Therefore $V$ is a real vector space

Answer (score 0):

It is mostly correct. However:

- You have asserted without justification that $(\theta\oplus\theta)\oplus\theta=\theta\oplus(\theta\oplus\theta)$. It is indeed true, but you did not explain why.
- The fourth property is not what you have stated. It is: for every $\alpha\in V$, there is some $\beta\in V$ such that $\alpha\oplus\beta=\theta$.
- You did not check that, if $r,s\in\Bbb R$ and if $\alpha\in V$, then $r\odot(s\odot\alpha)=(rs)\odot\alpha$.

Comment: (ii) holds because of associative law of vectors.